# Environment variables not available on server after mod_rewrite, but works locally

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, suexec, server-side-includes

I am working on a site where I am using SSI to set a variable on an HTML page that gets parsed and the variable is then to be picked up by a script after a `mod_rewrite` rewrite. This works on my local setup, but for some reason it doesn't on the production server (both are apache 2.2.22). Here are the relevant bits:

The `perl` script:

```
my $working = ($ENV{'HTTP_my_var'} || $ENV{'REDIRECT_HTTP_my_var'}) || "NO";
    
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "is it working? <b>$working</b>";
```

relevant lines from `.htaccess`

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.html [L]

RewriteRule ^my_tst$ /cgi-bin/my_tst.cgi [L]
```

The HTML file:

```
 <!--#set var="HTTP_my_var" value="YES" -->
 <!--#include virtual="/cgi-bin/my_tst.cgi" -->
 <br>
 <!--#include virtual="/my_tst" -->
```

This is the result on my local machine:

> is it working? **YES**
>
> is it working? **YES**

But on the production server:

> is it working? **YES**
>
> is it working? **NO**

Comparing the server configs the only thing that really pops to mind is that on the production server `httpd -M` does not list  `apreq_module (shared)`, and the local server does not list  `fcgid_module (shared)` (among others). Could it be due to any of these? What could be causing this strange mismatch in behavior?

In case it need mentioning, when I do a dump of `%ENV`, *none* of the **REDIRECT_*** variables appear in the production server in the rewrite part (the second `include` directive of the HTML), while they do on the local server, and the non-rewrite output of the include directive.

---

Edit: Adding another variable, *HTTP_my_var2* which is set in the .htaccess via a `SetEnv` directive, has no issues, ie, the value is not trashed in the rewrite.

However, setting the variable with `SetEnvIf` does trigger the problem,

---

Edit1: Confirmed, it seems there is a strange interaction between `mod_suexec`, `mod_rewrite` and `mod_include` (as well as `mod_setenvif`). I have successfully reproduced the problem locally by running it with `suexec` enabled. Disabling suexec by commenting out the `SuexecUserGroup` line in the `VirtualHost` entry (and restarting the server) produces the desired results. Now to investigate possible solutions.

This might actually be a bug in apache httpd.

Comment: Do you see anything different in the access logs? FWIW I get "YES" and "YES" (REDIRECT) for the 3 servers I've tried (Apache 2.2.9, 2.4.7 and 2.4.23).

Comment: Hi, thanks for testing. Not sure what the access logs would show, since the requests made are only for the uri ("/my_tst") and a couple things like css and an image (that's in fact the only entries in the access log locally, as well as on the production server)

Comment: By the way, would you happen to be able to give a httpd -M listing for me to compare with the production server's? Maybe that could yield some clues.

Comment: @w3dk I have narrowed it down to `suexec`, do you happen to have that configured and running in any of those apache versions you tested?

Answer (score 1):

It is documented behviour that Suexec clears out the environment prior to running a CGI script

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/env.html

> Some Caveats
>
> ...
> When suexec is used to launch CGI scripts, the environment will be cleaned down to a set of safe variables before CGI scripts are
> launched. The list of safe variables is defined at compile-time in
> suexec.c.

Comment: good to know. Thank you!